# Find web element for selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to click on Apply Now button

Apply Now

I have try with bunt did not work

```
WebElement Apply =driver.findElementByXPath("/a[text()[contains(.,' Apply Now ')]]");
```

Comment: Relative xpath start with "//" that's the issue in your xpath. instead of that you are using "/" which means Abs xpath. so this will throw an error.

Comment: Still not working

WebElement Apply =driver.findElementByXPath("//a[text()[contains(.,' Apply Now ')]]");
  Apply.click();

Answer (score 2):

I think that your xpath query was not ok. I would write it like this

```
WebElement applyButton = driver.findElementByXPath("//a[text() = 'Apply Now']");
applyButton.click()
```

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error? Can you post the new code that you've written?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()[contains(.,' Apply Now ')]]"}

Comment: From error I could tell that you are using your old xpath query and not query that I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for partial match using [XPath contains() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) would be:

```
WebElement Apply =driver.findElementByXPath("//a[contains(text(),'Apply now')]");
```

You might find [ByPartialLinkText](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByPartialLinkText.html) locator easier to use

```
WebElement Apply = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Apply Now"));
```

You might also want to wrap this into [WebDriverWait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/):

```
WebElement Apply = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By
                        .partialLinkText("Apply Now")));
```

And finally according to [Java naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) you might want to make this `Apply` to start with the lowercase `a`